# Error Handling in mysql not catching correct errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a relatively simple Multi Query with MySQLi.

The queries simply add data to 4 tables.

I am now trying to build in some error handling to give me a message if there is a duplicate and have come up with this:

```
if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Property Added: '$est_name'";
} else if (mysqli_errno() !== 1062) {
  print 'Error - Duplicate Entry!';
}
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Although I thought it worked initially, I soon found out the 'Error -Duplicate Entry!' was catching all errors, even those not duplicates!

Another thing that seams to be happening is that if I deliberately try to cause an error in any of the 3 query statements, after the first (i.e a typo) it continues the query and I am not given any error - I'm not sure if the problems are related!

**How do I build in error handling if there is a duplicate? (And is my problem with queries not 'erroring' related?)**

My queries Look something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table1 (fname, lname) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname');";

$sql .= "SELECT @get_ID := LAST_INSERT_ID();";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO Table2 (id, street_address ) VALUES (@get_ID, '$street_address');";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO Table3 (id, gender) VALUES (@get_ID, '$gender');";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO Table4 (id, rating) VALUES (@get_ID, '$rating');";
```

Comment: `!==` not equals, the oppersite of what you actully want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Silly mistake on my end forgot to add: `$conn`, and re ordered the statement.

```
if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Property Added: '$est_name'";
} else if (mysqli_errno($conn) !== 1062) {
  print 'Error - Duplicate Entry!';
}
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Looks like the other issue however regarding executing queries is unrelated as I am still experiencing it!